# Controlling an embeded player

Tags: javascript, wordpress, embed, soundcloud

I've got an embedded SC player on my page and I want the user to be able to jump to specific timecodes within the sound file from links on the page. I've got it working for the first click. But if the user then clicks on another link to a segment, the SC player ignores it. It just keeps playing along and ignores the input.

Here's my relevant code:

```
function playSC(seekto){
seekto = HMSToMS(seekto);
var container = document.getElementById("SCPlayer"); 
var iframe = container.getElementsByTagName("iframe"); 
var widgetIframe = iframe[0],
widget = SC.Widget(widgetIframe);       
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
    widget.play();
});
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function() {
    widget.seekTo(seekto); 
});
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.SEEK, function() {
    widget.unbind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY);
});
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PAUSE, function() {
    widget.unbind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY); 
}); 
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function() {
    widget.unbind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY); 
}); 

}
var container = document.getElementById("SCPlayer"); 
var iframe = container.getElementsByTagName("iframe"); 
var widgetIframe = iframe[0],
widget = SC.Widget(widgetIframe);

seekto = getParameterByName('t');
if (seekto){    
  (function(){
    playSC(seekto); 
  }());
}
```

The SC player is embedded via a Wordpress plugin and getting to it through the DOM is a little tricky because I can't just assign it a unique ID.

The href that the user clicks looks like this: javascript:playSC("00:01:21");

What am I missing here? On the second (or third or fourth) click why doesn't the player stop, seek to the new time and start playing again?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have answered my own question. Here's what I've got and it *seems* to be working.

```
function playSC(seekto){
    seekto = HMSToMS(seekto);
    var container = document.getElementById("SCPlayer"); 
    var iframe = container.getElementsByTagName("iframe"); 
    var widgetIframe = iframe[0],
    widget = SC.Widget(widgetIframe);           
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
        widget.play();
    });
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function() {
        widget.seekTo(seekto); 
    });
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY_PROGRESS, function() {
        widget.getPosition(function(pos) {
        seekto = pos;
      }); 
    }); 
}
```

Thoughts or advice? This seems to be working, but I'm not an experienced coder. I welcome your input.

Comment: With a little more testing it became clear this is only sort of working. Clicking the links sometimes causes the player to seek and play as expected, but other times does not.